# swap letters in a string in python

Tags: python

I am trying to switch the first character in a string and move it to the end of the string. It needs to repeat the rotation a number of n times.
For example, `rotateLeft(hello,2)=llohe`.

I tried doing

```
def rotateLeft(str,n):
    rotated=""
    rotated=str[n:]+str[:n]
    return rotated
```

Is this right, and how would you do it if it remove the last character and move it to the front of the string?

Comment: Maybe you could find something useful in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781380/how-do-i-swap-letters-around-from-an-input-in-python

Comment: I saw that before, but im trying to do something for all cases

Comment: "Is this right"... well, did you **test it**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can shorten it to

```
def rotate(strg,n):
    return strg[n:] + strg[:n]
```

and simply use negative indices to rotate "to the right":

```
>>> rotate("hello", 2)
'llohe'
>>> rotate("hello", -1)
'ohell'
>>> rotate("hello", 1)
'elloh'
>>> rotate("hello", 4)
'ohell'
>>> rotate("hello", -3)
'llohe'
>>> rotate("hello", 6)  # same with -6: no change if n > len(strg)
'hello'
```

If you want to keep rotating even after exceeding the length of the string, use

```
def rotate(strg,n):
    n = n % len(strg)
    return strg[n:] + strg[:n]
```

so you get

```
>>> rotate("hello", 1)
'elloh'
>>> rotate("hello", 6)
'elloh'
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the code you have posted is the fact that you're trying to use "str" as a name for a string. This is the name of a built in function in Python, and that's why you're getting errors. See more: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str You cannot use that as a name for something.

Changing the name of the string you pass rotateLeft will solve your problem.

```
def rotateLeft(string,n):
    rotated=""
    rotated=string[n:]+string[:n]
    return rotated
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

s = 'Impending doom approaches!'
d = deque(s)
d.rotate(11)
print(''.join(d))
>>> approaches!Impending doom
d.rotate(-21)
print(''.join(d))
>>> doom approaches!Impending
```